# PHP echo display - Missing Information

Tags: php, echo

I'm trying fix my .php file, but i'm find some problems ..

I need the received the output from my script, using echo or print functions, but the echo result are displayed incompleted .

This is my .php :

```
<?php
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');

require_once "PHPTelnet.php";

$SUBSCRIBER = $_POST["SUBSCRIBER"];

$COUNT = $_POST["COUNT"];


if ($SUBSCRIBER == "HOME")

{
        echo "It's HOME<br>";

        if ($COUNT=="ACTIVE_FLOW")

        {

        echo "Value is ACTIVE_FLOW";

        $script = "exec cf2:/scripts/active_flow_count.cfg";

        }
}

echo "<pre>";

echo "<pre>";
```

My echo output is that :

```
It's HOME
Value is ACTIVE_FLOW
exec cf2:/scripts/active_flow_count.cfg 

=====================================================
Application-Assurance flow record search, Version 1.0
Search Start Time:     "12/12/2012 22:23:08" (UTC)
 Search Criteria:
  group[:partition]:   1:1
  aa-sub:              1/1/1:302 (sap)
  protocol name:       none specified
  application name:    none specified
  app-group name:      none specified
  flow-status:         active
  start-flowId:        none specified
  classified:          none specified
  server-ip:           none specified
  server-port:         none specified
  client-ip:           none specified
  bytes-tx:            none specified
  flow-duration:       none specified
  max-count:           none specified
  search-type:         default
=====================================================
FlowId  Init  Src-ip                                  Dst-ip                                  Ip-prot     Src-prt Dst-prt Protocol               Application            Pkts-tx    Bytes-tx             Pkts-disc  Bytes-disc Time-ofp(UTC)         Time-olp(UTC)        
2107678 no    200.141.223.79                          10.101.75.199                           tcp         57238   1356    "ftp_data"             "FTP"                  687100     1026970850           0          0          "12/12/2012 21:00:46" "12/12/2012 22:23:09"
```

It should contain many more lines than this.

Is there any possibility to echo stop when they see this "12/12/2012 22:23:09" double quotes ?

Comment: What do you want it to echo?

Comment: do you mean stop the echo or a literal stop?

Comment: What is in `PHPTelnet.php`?

Comment: You haven't shown what happens after `$script='..'` - that isn't echo'd there so there is some more code you need to supply

Answer (score 0):

If you mean echo the word "stop" when this exact date and time appears somewhere you could do

```
if(preg_match("/\b\"12\/12\/2012 22:23:09\"\b/i")==true)
{
    echo "stop"
}
```

Comment: Because they said it should contain more lines I think by "Is there any possibility to echo stop when they see this..." they meant "Is there any possibility PHP will stop echoing when it sees this..."

Answer (score 0):

Your not showing the important parts of the script. What you need to do is process the output before displaying it, which means loading it into a string rather then echo()'ing it directly, or using an output buffer to catch the echo()'ed content. Then you want to find the posistion of "12/12/2012 22:23:09" and use substr to get it and the contents of the string before it. Note the code below would be MUCH better off using a regex to find the position, but this is a example to show how it would work.

It would be something like this:

```
<?php

//....

ob_start();
if ($SUBSCRIBER == "HOME")

{
        echo "It's HOME<br>";

        if ($COUNT=="ACTIVE_FLOW")

        {

        echo "Value is ACTIVE_FLOW";

        $script = "exec cf2:/scripts/active_flow_count.cfg";

        }
}
$out = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

// Should use requex but this will work
// Find the pos of "Start Time:" then add 22 for the chars in '"xx/xx/xxxx xx:xx:xx"'
$pos = strpos($out, "Start Time:")+22;
echo substr($out, 0, $pos);

//....

?>
```